# Why don't the minus ends of microtubules shrink?

Tags: cell-biology

Is this because $\alpha$-tubulin is always in the GTP state? Or is it because $\gamma$-TuRC stabilizes the minus end?

Comment: Depolymerization of microtubules does occur at both ends, it is only that the kinetics are different at the plus-end than at the minus-end. Due to dynamic instability, depolymerization occurs about 100 times faster at the GDP end than the GTP end, but both will depolymerize, just at different rates.